# Convert DD-MM-YYYY format to MM-DD-YYYY in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to convert a date from **DD-MM-YYYY** to **MM-DD-YYYY**. But it doesn't work for me. I tried this

```js
var test = Date.parse('15-06-2010');
var SearchDate = moment('15-06-2010').format("MM-DD-YYYY");

var day = moment(new Date("15-06-2010"), "MM-DD-YYYY");

console.log(test);
console.log(day);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Help me.

Answer (score 34):

Try this:

```
var date = moment('15-06-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
console.log(date.format('MM-DD-YYYY'))
```

You have to specify the input format for the date when parsing a date with momentjs.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 20):

Here 26-11-2019 will be converted to 11-26-2019

```
const date =  moment('26-11-2019','DD-MM-YYYY').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

To the format method we can give any format, how you want the output.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
moment(moment('15-06-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY')).format('MM-DD-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 3):

I have to validate the date using momentjs. So following works for me :).

```
var dateValidate = moment(startDate).isValid() || moment(startDate, "DD/MM/YYYY").isValid() ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
var formatDate= 1399919400000;

var responseDate = moment(formatDate).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```